# Special format of date in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

A customer wants a special format of a date column in excel.

What he wants is that the date (for example `02.06.2014` and formatted as **short-date**) changes to a **number (41792)** when the format changes to `General`.

Unfortunately, my date column doesn't change the value at all when the format is changed from `short-date` to `general`...

Do you know how it is possible to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your customer is trying to tell you is that however you're generating dates is ending up with a character string instead of a date value that Excel understands.

If the text format of your date column is because you are typing periods into Excel when entering dates: **STOP**. Enter dates with slashes and Excel will recognize it as a date:

[image: "9/1/2015" typed into an Excel cell]
Just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you click on the cell, you'll see that Excel formatted your entry as a Date for you.

[image: Excel "Date" format]

If you are somehow generating this spreadsheet from another program, you'll have to ask another question about how to output Excel-friendly dates from that program, but the bottom line is that it'll have to be a number counting the days since Dec 31, 1899 (Jan 1, 1900 is `1` for Excel dates).

To convert the data that has already been generated, see Microsoft's helpful page: [Convert dates stored as text to dates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-dates-stored-as-text-to-dates-8df7663e-98e6-4295-96e4-32a67ec0a680).